# Unprecedented file save issue

Tags: python, windows

Couple minutes ago, I created a new python file, It did not work in Sublime(without errors, just didn't build) , so I wanted to try it in IDLE, And when I tried to save it(Ctrl-S), Here is the issue I faced.

[image: Save issue]

I did not yet try to delete and recreate the file because I would like to know what would have caused such an interesting problem. The file is right there, and it cannot be saved. It is on desktop so it cannot be about security permissions.

I use 64 bit Windows 10 OS.

**Edit1:** When I open it with sublime or Idle, it appears as a complete blank file(Because it cannot be saved). However when I open it with notepad, the whole code is there and saved. Da hell is happening ?

Comment: Did you remove or rename the folder it is in?

Comment: You have some sort of unrecognized character in the file that is breaking your fancy editors, but that notepad doesn't care about.  Smart quotes maybe?

Comment: I did not do any chance to the folders. And Paul, isn't file names supposed to support unicode ? Because I have one character in the folder name that is not ascii.

Comment: The file system supports Unicode file names.  That doesn't mean that any particular piece of software that manipulates files necessarily supports Unicode file names.

Comment: Unicode support in IDLE 2.x is very bad, especially on Windows. It should work fine in IDLE 3.x.

Comment: `Run as Administrator`